# Convert HTML/CSS to image (png, or any loseless format) in R

Tags: html, css, r, image, file-conversion

I would like to make a piece of code in R that takes a HTML/CSS page and makes a picture of it. I haven't fount any package in R that makes this process easy.

I've found `wkhtmltopdf` but it converts HTML to PDF and then I would have to save it as an image.

Have you found any way to do this, preferably inside R?

Comment: I've found `wkhtmltoimage`... let's try it.. But it's not a R package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rselenium` for that.
Have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html

```
require(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                      , port = 4444
                      , browserName = "firefox"
                      )
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.r-project.org/")
remDr$maxWindowSize()
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

This example is taken from there

Comment: This answer is correct, as it performs what I've stated in the question: Making an image out of an HTML/CSS file, using R. Thank you a lot! I have to change the windows size, as the page is so small, and I have to read it from a file. It's a great solution!